# Como usar o destructuring assignment para construir um novo objeto com atributos em comum?

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho um array com os seguintes objetos:

```
0: {nome: "Ricardo Graciolli", id: "2", atendimentos: "12", horario: "12:00"}
1: {nome: "Ana Paula Germano", id: "3", atendimentos: "12", horario: "07:00"}
2: {nome: "Ricardo Graciolli", id: "2", atendimentos: "15", horario: "07:00"}
```

E gostaria de um resultado que me retornasse um array mais ou menos assim:

```
[{
        nome: "Ricardo Graciolli",
        id: "2",
        horarios: [{
            horario: "12:00",
            atendimentos: "16"
        }, {
            horario: "07:00",
            atendimentos: "12"
        }]
    },
    {
        nome: "Ana Paula Germano",
        id: "3",
        horarios: [{
            horario: "07:00",
            atendimentos: "12"
        }]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisa usar *destructuring assignment*? Eu acho que precisar, não precisa...

```js
let dados = [
  {nome: "Ricardo Graciolli", id: "2", atendimentos: "12", horario: "12:00"},
  {nome: "Ana Paula Germano", id: "3", atendimentos: "12", horario: "07:00"},
  {nome: "Ricardo Graciolli", id: "2", atendimentos: "15", horario: "07:00"}
];

let result = {};
for (const dado of dados) {
    let obj_horario = { horario: dado.horario, atendimentos: dado.atendimentos };
    if (result[dado.id]) { // se já existe o id nos resultados, acrescenta os horários
        result[dado.id].horarios.push(obj_horario);
    } else { // se não existe o id nos resultados, cria um novo
        result[dado.id] = {
            nome: dado.nome, id: dado.id,
            horarios: [ obj_horario ]
        };
    }
}

result = Object.values(result);
console.log(result);
```

Primeiro você cria um objeto cujas chaves serão os id's, e os valores são os objetos que você quer criar (o que tem nome, id e horários).

Aí basta ver se o id já existe no objeto. Se não existir, cria um objeto novo. Se já existir, basta adicionar o novo horário no já existente.

No final, use `Object.values` para pegar apenas os valores do `result`. O resultado será o array que você quer.

Comment: Eu ia editar o título justamente por isso! O destructuring assignment foi a forma que estava pensando pra resolver o problema, mas não tem necessidade de fato. A sua resposta era exatamente o que eu procurava. Muito obrigado!